# Calling the function in setup in Processing

Tags: function, processing, call

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
int year;
boolean is_leap_year(int year)
{
 if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
    return true;
 else
    return false;
}

void setup ()
{
 String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a year or a negative number to test");
 year = Integer.parseInt(answer);

 while (year > 0) {
 boolean b = is_leap_year(year);
 if (b == true) {
 println( year + " is a leap year");
 }
 else{
 println( year + " is Not a leap year");
 answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a year or a negative number to test");
 year = Integer.parseInt(answer);
 }
}
}
```

I wrote the function is_leap_year to test if the input is a leap year or not. However, the program won't run on the basis of one error.

> (Line 3) "This method must return a result of type boolean."

Haven't I already done that, because I put boolean as the function type in the header? I also put return true as the block of the if statement.

Also, I'm not sure if the function can be called properly from setup. I feel as though I'm missing something.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

> Edit: (Line 7 and 8) I completed it and added the else to return false.
>   For some reason, Processing is crashing after printing "2000 is a leap year" in multiple lines when I input 2000. Is there an infinite loop going on? How do I fix it?

Comment: What value will your method return for non-leap year?

Comment: Oh wow I completely forgot about that. Guess I should write else() return false.

Comment: @PM77-1                                                                                                                    Hey, I put in the else statement to return false, but processing is crashing after printing multiple lines. Is there an infinite loop of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

Run through your program in your head, or with a piece of paper and a pencil. Take it one line at a time:

```
  String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a year or a negative number to test");
  year = Integer.parseInt(answer);
```

This line gets a year from a user. Let's say the user enters `2000`.

```
  while (year > 0) {
```

So now we're looping. `2000 > 0`, so we enter the `while` loop.

```
boolean b = is_leap_year(year);
```

This tests whether the year is a leap year. `2000` is a leap year, so `b` is `true`.

```
 if (b == true) {
      println( year + " is a leap year");
 }
```

Since `b` is `true`, this gets printed out.

```
else {
      println( year + " is Not a leap year");
      answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a year or a negative number to test");
      year = Integer.parseInt(answer);
    }
```

Our `b` variable is still `true`, so **this code is skipped**. We then go back to the `while` loop.

```
while (year > 0) {
```

Our `year` variable is still `2000`, so we just repeat the above again, and again, and again.

The problem is: if it's a leap year, you never ask for another year. You just keep looping on the same year, which will cause an infinite loop and might cause Processing to crash.

To fix this problem, you need to ask for a new year in both cases.